# Qual é a diferença entre text() e html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual é a diferença entre `text()` e `html()`?

```
$("#div").html('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>');
```

**vs**

```
$("#div").text('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>');
```

Qual é o melhor para usar e em quais condições?